# Update ListMap and preserve order in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a basic immutable ListMap that preserves the order of items nicely. However I want to update an existing key in the ListMap at some point, but the order of that specific key is lost.

```
val myListMap = ListMap(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar")
val myListMap2 = myListMap.updated(1, "foo2")
// myListMap2: ListMap[Int,String] = Map(2 -> bar, 1 -> foo2)
```

How can I update a ListMap without losing the position of an existing key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a coincidence the way `ListMap` is built. `ListMap` is not really a defined API in itself, but just an implementation of `Map`. I would recommend to use the abstract type instead, i.e. `Map(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar")`.

If you need your map to be sorted, use the dedicated `SortedMap` interface.

```
import collection.immutable.SortedMap
val m0 = SortedMap(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar")
val m1 = m0.updated(1, "baz")
val m2 = m1 + (0 -> "abc")
```

Comment: Looks like SortedMap won't suffice. I need to preserve a specific, custom order. A more accurate example: `ListMap("color" -> "green", "country" -> "Germany")`

Comment: Then you should maintain a separate `List` or `Vector` that is a linear sequence.

Comment: That seems like an doable solution, however introduces a small overhead.

Comment: You can't have both, O(1) `get` and random stable insertion order. Do you need the `Map` interface at all? If your collection is not extremely large, you can find elements in a `Vector` using `indexOf` / `indexWhere`.

Comment: I find the map easy to work with, because I need to access data by key and the key itself has a role too. The working set is not large at all.

Comment: Could it be a viable option to substitute ListMap with a List[(String, String)]? It seems to be working just fine, and luckily enough it even worked with a pattern matching for ListMap somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re just interested in the Map API and not in insertion performances, you may do something like this :

```
val myListMap = ListMap(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar")
val myListMap2 = myListMap.map(c => if(c._1 == 1) c._1 -> "foo2" else c)
```

Insertion order is untouched this way.